# Setting CORS on PHP to allow certain domains

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I am trying to get CORS to work on my PHP and it is not working. I only want certain domains to have access to my php file.
I have looked at other articles on Stackoverlflow (ie [Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers)), but couldn't get it to work as my $SERVER[ORIGIN] always returns null;

This is my https://dev.mycompany.com/test-cors.php file:

```
 <?

     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.mycompany.com");
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
     header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");    
     $myObj->name = "John";
     $myObj->age = 30;
     $myObj->city = "New York";

     $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

     echo $myJSON;

 ?>
```

I am trying to call the json.php with ajax from my https://dev.mycompany.com server to see if I would get JSON data back. I was expecting to get an error, but instead got the data retrieved alert message.

Here is my jquery call from the dev server on ajax.js.

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "test-cors.php",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json', // added data type
            success: function(data) {
                    alert('data retrieved');

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert(textStatus);
            }
    
});
```

Comment: Your ajax request is made to the to the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). CORS only works for cross origin. (Hence the name.)

Answer (score 0):

The `origin` header is a header your browser sends to the server, indicating the origin (domain) of the request. In your case, `test-core.php` is on the same origin (dev.mycompany.com) as the Ajax call and thus allowed. The CORS headers are ignored. When performing this request from another origin (for ex. localhost) it would fail.

> I only want certain domains to have access to my php file.

Please  be aware that CORS headers are not a way to specify "access" some url/file. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header limits **browsers** to perform requests to a certain url while on a certain location (for example, are you allowed to call an API on yoursite[.]com while the browser is on stackoverflow.com). It has nothing to do with actual access management.